# How to switch off/on network in xamarin android/iOS app from xamarin uitest in C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, ui-automation, uitest

I am writing xamarin uitest in c# to automate xamarin mobile app.I have apk and ipa file with me.I want to toggle network connection after launching the app.How to switch on/off the network using uitest.
In appium we can use togglewifi() to change state.Is there any method available in xamarin?

Comment: Please research your questions before posting on SO. [This](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/wifi-onoff-on-button-click-in-xamarin-android) C# Corner blog entry describes how to turn on/off wifi in xamarin (which I found after a few seconds of googling)

Answer (score 1):

We could not open/close wifi in code behind in Xamarin for iOS . But you can open the setting page after launch the app.

You can use **DependencyService** if you call it in Forms

> in iOS

```
using xxx.iOS;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(OpenSettingsImplement))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class OpenSettingsImplement : ISettingsService
    {
        public void OpenSettings()
        {
            var url = new NSUrl($"App-Prefs:");
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url);
        }
    }
}
```

> in Android

```
using Android.Content;

using xxx;
using xxx.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(OpenSettingsImplement))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
    public class OpenSettingsImplement : ISettingsService
    {
        public void OpenSettings()
        {
            Intent intentOpenSettings = new Intent();
            intentOpenSettings.SetAction(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionAirplaneModeSettings);
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intentOpenSettings);
        }
    }
}
```

> in Forms,add a new interface

```
public interface ISettingsService
{
  void OpenSettings();
}
```